# How to split up the url?

Tags: esb, mule

I use Mule Studio.

When I run for example **localhost:8080/?first=value1&second=value2** I would like to get two variables and their values:

first: value1
second: value2

I use *splitter* to delete first '/' like this:

```
[regex('/(.*?)', message.payload)]
```

but now I get:

```
?first=value1&second=value2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the parameters by using message.inboundProperties['parameter'].

For example:

```
    <logger level="WARN" message="#[message.inboundProperties['first']]" />
    <logger level="WARN" message="#[message.inboundProperties['second']]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the parameters in three ways:

- Directly from the message's inbound properties
- As a Map by accessing the inbound property keyed with `http.query.params`
- Using http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer and have the map conveniently placed on the payload.

Consider running the following flow:

```
<flow name="mule-configFlow1" doc:name="mule-configFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8082/app" />
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
    <logger level="ERROR" />
    <logger level="ERROR" message="Payload is: #[payload]" />
    <json:object-to-json-transformer />
</flow>
```